# Pear Crypt/HMAC.php failed to open stream

Tags: php, pear, hmac

I am on a MediaTemple Dedicated Virtual server and have enabled Pear using the instructions found at:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/514/Enabling+PEAR+by+setting+your+open_basedir+and+include_path

Here's the problem...

In my PHP script, I have this:

```
require_once 'Crypt/HMAC.php';
```

When I execute the script, I get this message:

```
S3::require_once(Crypt/HMAC.php) [s3.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It's a script for integrating with Amazon S3. When we were on the Grid service it worked fine. I've only had problems since moving to a DV server.

I installed the HMAC pear module using this command:

```
pear install Crypt_HMAC
```

Then re-started the server. Still no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch if you can help :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your include path to also mention the PEAR directory on your server, you can either do this in a .htaccess file or with the set_include_path function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `require_once 'Crypt_HMAC.php';`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. I get the exact same error: S3::require_once(Crypt_HMAC.php) [s3.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Within the Pear directory on my server, the file is located at Crypt/HMAC.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo pear install Crypt_HMAC2
```